Problem sorting devices received from navigator.usb.getDevices
I am using Electron and node.js and have problems talking to several identical USB devices (sensors) differing only in their serial number.
How can I sort USB devices (same manufacturerName and same productName, but different serialNumber)?
If I try to sort the deviceList as in the code below I get "undefined" in my renderer.js
serial.js
var serial = {};

(function() {
  'use strict';

  serial.getDevices = async function() {
    console.log('FCT: getDevices');
    return navigator.usb.getDevices().then(devices => {
      const deviceList  = [];

      devices.forEach(async (element) => {
        if (element.manufacturerName==='Tardy' && 
            element.productName == 'T-BOS V3.0'){
          deviceList.push(await new serial.Port(element)) 
        } 
      })

      deviceList.sort((a, b) =>  a.serialNumber < b.serialNumber ? -1 : 1 );

      return deviceList;
    });
  }

...

renderer.js
      serial.getDevices().then(ports => {
        console.log('App: getPorts: ', ports);
        if (ports.length === 0) {
          statusDisplay.textContent = 'No device found.';
        } else {
          statusDisplay.textContent = 'Connecting...';

          Array.from(ports).forEach((element) => {
            console.log("Port: ", element)
          });

          port = ports[0];

          connect();  // uses port to connect to
        }

In renderer I cannot access any members of the returned deviceList (in renderer e.g. port[x].manufacturerName)
I prefer if I could sort the returned devices in my renderer.js.
Searching the net did not get me towards any solution...
Thanks
GvTT

I really assume sorting doesn't have anything to do with sorting per se. What happens if you remove the line deviceList.sort?

And what do you mean by "I get undefined"?

If I remove  deviceList.sort I can read all the attaches USB devices... The order they get listed varies each time I start the application.
By "I get 'undefined'" I mean: the variable has no value assigned. The HTML element shows "undefined, so does console.log(Object.keys(...).

That doesn't make any sense, because sort doesn't change the elements in the array, just their order. What variable has no value assiged? The only thing I can image is, that your devices list contains a value of undefined and this values is sorted to be the first element, thus ports[0] (ie the only value you access from your resulting list) is therefore undefined.

But your question is missing far to many details to be able to provide any meaningful help. Show for for instance what devicvesList looks like before and after you apply sort,

You seem to be using both the WebUSB (navigator.usb) and Web Serial APIs. Let's assume you just want to use Web Serial. In Electron, you need to use mainWindow.webContents.session.on('select-serial-port', (event, portList, webContents, callback) in the main process to list and select ports. Useful example code can be found at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devices#web-serial-api
Note that serial numbers may not be available on all platforms. On Windows, you may need to extract the serial number from the deviceInstanceId.

thanks for the link, indeed this is where I pulled some of my code...
I fiddled some more with my code and managed to get it running:
serial.js
    // get available USB devices 
serial.getPorts = async function() {
  console.log('Ser: getPorts'); 
  return navigator.usb.getDevices().then( devices => { // get WinUSB devices 
    console.log('getPorts: devices: ',devices)
    const deviceList = [];

    devices.sort((a, b) =>  a.serialNumber < b.serialNumber ? -1 : 1 );   // sort devices by serial number

    devices.forEach(element => {                    // list only devices of interest
      if (element.manufacturerName === 'Tardy' &&     
          element.productName === 'T-BOS 3.0')
        deviceList.push(new serial.Port(element));               
    });

    deviceList.forEach( element => {
      let listed = false; 

      // Check is the channel is already listed in channelListe
      channelList.forEach((item) => {                 // check if has already been listed
        if (item.serialNumber === element.device_.serialNumber) {
          listed = true;      
        }
      })

      // Not listed => Push the port to channelList... this creates a new entry...
      if (listed != true) {
        channelList.push(new channel(element.device_.productName + ' ' + element.device_.serialNumber, element.device_.serialNumber, 0));
      } 
    });

    console.log('getPorts: deviceList: ',deviceList)
    return deviceList;
  });
};

is working for me now.
I missed the need to add .device_. to access the entries of deviceList.
When pushing elements of devices (devices.forEach( element => ...) into my deviceList then .device_. is added? Any hint on this?
As you can see at the arrow device_ is added in deviceList
Greetings
GvTT
